# python beautiful soup issue with href class

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
...code ommited...
tda = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("https://link/browse/[A-Z]{2,4}-[0-9]{1,7}"), "class":"external-link"}) # Find all A tag with specific href    

...code ommited...

first_end_tag_index = a_tag_as_str.find(">")

a_tag_as_str_index = "".join(html_as_list).find(a_tag_as_str[:first_end_tag_index + 1])

...code ommited...
 
OUTPUT:
first_end_tag_index:  90

a_tag_as_str_index:  -1
```

When my anchor is like

```
"<a href="https://link/browse/DDD-0001" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">DDD-0001</a>"
```

I get -1 when is like

```
"<a class="external-link" href="https://link/browse/DDD-0001" rel="nofollow">DDD-0001</a>"
```

I get > -1

What I am missing?
Why the beautiful soup expect the class to be before the href?

Is any way to make it not to check there the class is?

Comment: The second tag is missing the ``class`` attribute

Comment: @sushanth No it is not. it's on other position

Comment: Are you sure this is a  problem with the `BeautifulSoup.findAll()`? I minimally tested locally and it seems to work. Isn't this a problem from another part of your code?

Comment: What is the state of the `tda` variable?

Comment: in tda it has ```[<a class="external-l...A-0001</a>, <a class="external-l...A-0001</a>,``` . All the anchor on the file has class after the href and not before

Comment: I run the following code ``` soup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
  
    tag = soup.a
    attribute = tag.attrs
      # Print the output
    print(attribute)  ```  and I got those results ```oup = BeautifulSoup(html_string)
{'class': ['external-link'], 'href': 'https://link/browse/DDD-0001', 'rel': ['nofollow']}``` . I t seems that expect the class to be before the href and not after

Comment: @MaiconMauricio what code did you use for testing and it was successful?

Comment: Is there a public url you are using?

Comment: @QHarr No I read from a file

Comment: @yskapell I simply instantiated a `BeautifulSoup` object with the both `<a>` tags in your example enclosed by the `<html>` and `<body>` tags. `soup = BeautifulSoup('<html><body><a href="https://link/browse/DDD-0001" class="external-link" rel="nofollow">DDD-0001</a><a class="external-link" href="https://link/browse/DDD-0001" rel="nofollow">DDD-0001</a><body/><html/>')` > `tda = soup.findAll('a', attrs={'href': re.compile("https://link/browse/[A-Z]{2,4}-[0-9]{1,7}"), "class":"external-link"})`. `tda` state has both tags in it.

Comment: @MaiconMauricio If you use the code I paste you will see that the index is 0 for all links